# CSS 3D Transform Angle Issue

Tags: css, css-transforms

I'm using CSS3 to perform the following transformation on a div:

`'-webkit-transform' : 'rotateX(45deg) rotateZ(-45deg)'`

The result is like:

[image]

Or as in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kteSW/

As we can see here, the angle is 36deg, instead of 30deg (sin45*sin45).
Does anyone know the reason for this problem? Is this intended or is it a CSS3 bug?

---

UPDATE:

I've already set the parameters to be:

`-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-perspective: none;`

So everything should be rendering in a orthogonal way. However, the angle is still not 30deg.

Comment: Your calculations are assuming an isometric rendering model. CSS 3D uses [perspective 3D rendering](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-3d-transforms/#transform-rendering).

Comment: Thanks Raymond. Is there a way to enable isometric rendering of CSS 3D? We're using WebKit on iOS.

Comment: Transforms are not transitions - please do not mix the two of them up. I've edited the tags for you.

Comment: can you jsfiddle so that I can test it on my browser and do some updation to it?

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava Sure. http://jsfiddle.net/kteSW/

Comment: @FelixChan http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles this will help you why it is rotate in 36 deg as you are rotating in X Z direction so whole will be changed for finding angles

Comment: Try following the [advice here](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/3d-transforms-isocube/) of adding a skew to compensate.

Answer (score 6):

What we are trying to achieve is to calculate the angle between the eye and the Z axis when we look at (0, 0, 0) from (1, 1, 1).

So it is actually `(90 deg) - arctan(1 / sqrt(2)) = 54.7356103 deg`, not `45deg`.